# Can i export images(assets) from a Contentful space, to my machine?

Tags: contentful

I need the same assets from a Contentful account, to a second one. Couldn't find nothing on this, only tutorials on how to import/export from Contentful to an app, or between spaces of the same account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import export works between spaces of different accounts as well. You would first export from one space and then re-import it to another, making sure to update access tokens in between.

Comment: Thank you! i didn't realised that.